# Presenting a View controller over an UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have a View controller 1 and I present an `UIAlertController` over it on click of a Button. Then I present a View Controller 2 over `UIAlertController`. When I dismiss the presented view controller 2 then position of `UIAlertController` seems to be changed like the one in the image. How to resolve it ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
        [button1 setCenter:self.view.center];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button1 setTitle:@"Present Alert" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
      [self.view addSubview:button1];  
    }


-(void)showAlert
    {
      UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert 1" message:@"1" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
      [alert1 addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
         }] ];
      [self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];

       ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
       [alert1 presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Inside ViewController2,

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
           [super viewDidLoad];
           self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

          UIButton *dismissVC = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
           [dismissVC setCenter:self.view.center];
           [dismissVC setTitle:@"Dismiss" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [dismissVC addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [self.view addSubview:dismissVC];
         }

-(void)dismiss
    {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

[image: Alert controller Image]

Comment: you want show alert in center or you want dismiss it.?

Comment: I want the alert to be show in center .

Comment: Show me the code you present it ?

Comment: Show us your coding.Then only we can give the solution.

Comment: Edited the code have a look